# Problem to read from other appsetting file in IConfiguration

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, appsettings, .net-core-3.1

I have a webapi project in .net Core 3.1 and also i have 2 appsettings file `appsettings.json` and `appsettingsTest.json`

appsettings.json file:

```
{
"Section": {
"Mofid": "appSettings.json"
}
}
```

appsettingsTest.json file:

```
{
"Section": {
    "Mofid": "appSettingsTest.json"
}
}
```

I wrote this code in constructor of `startup.cs` class

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettingsTest.json")
            .Build();

        Configuration = configuration;
    }
```

In controller I injected `IOptins<T>` and `IConfiguration` and I have 2 action.

First action read a value of setting with `IOptions` and other one read a value from `IConfiguration`

```
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly MofidOption _option;

    public WeatherForecastController(
        IOptions<MofidOption> options,
        IConfiguration configuration
        )
    {
        _option = options.Value;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get1()
    {
        return _option.Mofid; //read from appsettingsTest.json
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public string Get2()
    {
        return _configuration["Section:Mofid"]; //read from appsettings.json
    }
}
```

My problem is that `IConfiguration` reads from `appsettings.json` and `IOptions` reads from `appsettingsTest.json`

I wanna `IConfiguration` reads from `appsettingsTest.json`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify the configuration in Startup constructor, you would need to register it with DI framework.

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
```

You should ideally change the configuration from CreateHostBuilder method.

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile("MyConfig.json",
                optional: true,
                reloadOnChange: true);
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```